# Amazon Cognito - OAuth login for federated identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to handle the user login for my web application. My users login using their [SmartThings](https://account.smartthings.com/login) account and I currently have an OAuth flow where I set up an application in SmartThings get the App ID, client ID and then the Access and Refresh token from the user once they login. I want to transfer this over to Amazon Cognito.

I have tried to setup a `identity pool` in Amazon Cognito however it does not seem that the SmartThings method is natively supported. The options that are given are shown below.

[image]

It was my assumption that I could use any federation that supports OAuth with AWS Cognito but now I am not too sure. I see there is a `Custom` tab but that seems to be creating your own authentication method and not using the federation if I am correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We just did something similar with Okta and I think it's the SAML option that you want. The trick will be to get the correct SAML info for the SmartThings identity provider (which I know nothing about).